# How to Set a ConstraintLayout View to Percent Min Height

Tags: android, xml, view, textview, android-constraintlayout

I am using a ConstraintLayout and I want to create a TextView that takes up 30% of the height of the screen or the size of its content, whichever is greater.

I can use constraints to make it take up 30% of the screen via a horizontal guideline, and I can leave off those constraints to make it grow/shrink with the size of the text. However, I can't get it to do both --- that is, be 30% as a minimum but grow beyond that if needed.

I tried using `layout_constraintHeight_min` and setting it to a percent, to a guideline, and to a view with a set height, but none of those works. I know it will work if I put in a hardcoded value like 200dp, but I want the value to be proportional --- that is, a percent.

I essentially want something like this, though as I mentioned above, this code doesn't work because technically a guideline has a height of 0:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:text="MyText" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />
```

I also tried

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="@+id/heightGuide"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:text="MyText" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/heightGuide"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
        
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />
```

but that doesn't work either.

How can I make a view have a minimum height that is a proportion of the parent, but also allow it to grow beyond that height if needed?

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with a similar situation and finally managed to solve it by adding the following to my view:

```
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.66"
```

Hope this works for you